# Generic higher order function parameter type

Tags: typescript

When creating a function with a generic function parameter, is there a way to prevent bad utilization of the parameter?

The perceived standard case types the function as "any function whatsoever" inside:

```
const rip = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(f: T) => f('invalid');
rip((a: number) => a.toFixed(2)); // oops
```

Given `any` is a boo-doo and makes everything bivariant, i tried the following, but it still doesn't account for number of parameters:

```
const rip2 = <T extends (...args: readonly never[]) => unknown>(f: T) => f();
rip2((a: number) => a.toFixed(2)); // oops again
```

This has likely been asked before, but searching for it proved difficult for me (too many similar topics around "generic" and "higher order").

---

To avoid XY-problems, the origin of the problem is writing a function, which wraps functions with a check. Here is how i first intended to write it:

```
declare const check: () => boolean;
const checked = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(f: T): (...args: Parameters<T>) => 
ReturnType<T> | undefined => (...args) => {
  if (check()) return;
  return f(...args); // `f('invalid')` would not cause an error
};
const g = checked((a: number) => a.toFixed(2));
```

It suffers from the same issue. Inside, the function is `(...args: any[]) => any`, and therefore has no checks. Similar to above, a more strict constraint doesn't solve the issue entirely (no parameters still works), `readonly` causes an error, and a cast is necessary:

```
declare const check: () => boolean;
const checked = <T extends (...args: /* readonly */ never[]) => unknown>(f: T): (...args: 
Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> | undefined => (...args) => {
  if (check()) return;
  return f(...args) as ReturnType<T>; // `f()` would not cause an error
};
const g = checked((a: number) => a.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: How about being more explicit with your argment and return types? [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0QC3AawC54AKASngF4A+eAIySQhChQG4AoZdLMXMPEMErwAPAEF4IAB4YQKYGngsAngG0AugBp4AJSrEAZkWIA6M7ADmaImPLVdpY2ZOXr8W5Srt4P3fAA+8ACu8iAGAJYogp4kzq52NADe3r6p4QYkvPhk5HAYQTBsKak+eQUo8Aam5jBWpBypAL4cXJjwFsJZ-ILExFBEKEEAtrQgMAlKJhhIAGLhUj0ATKT1QA)

Comment: @spender - That looks good!

Comment: It does indeed look good, and solves the immediate problem. When being "more explicit" like that, TS correctly notices the "but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'". I'm still a bit confused about whether allowing the bad calls in the other scenario is a problem, unavoidable, or difficult and not (yet) solved in TS. However, for that, i guess i'll read a ton of articles about the general concepts involved.

Comment: I'm no expert on the ins and outs of type inference, but have found that I have a much higher success rate with HO functions when I split args and return-type onto their own generic parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By being more specific with types (i.e. creating a separate generic type for args and return-type, rather than inferring them from a single function type), TypeScript is better able to deduce that something's wrong if the function is supplied incorrect parameters.

```
declare const check: () => boolean;
const checked = <A extends any[], R>(f: (...args: A) => R): (...args: A) =>
    R | undefined => (...args) => {
        if (check()) return;
        return f(...args);
    };
const g = checked((a: number) => a.toFixed(2));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0QC3AawC54AKASngF4A+eAIySQhChQG4AoZdLMXMPEMErwAPAEF4IAB4YQKYGngsAngG0AugBp4AJSrEAZkWIA6M7ADmaImPLVdpY2ZOXr8W5Srt4P3fAA+8ACu8iAGAJYogp4kzq52NADe3r6p4QYkvPhk5HAYQTBsKak+eQUo8Aam5jBWpBypAL4cXJjwFsJZ-ILExFBEKEEAtrQgMAlKJhhIAGLhUj0ATKT1QA)